# Regex and greediness - how to write that expression using PHP?

Tags: php, regex

I have this string:

```
http://localhost/whatever/index.php/something/cms-abc.html?___SID=U
```

I want to get the **cms-abc** from that string. I tried:

```
/cms-.+/
```

But this will give me the stuff behind cms-abc as well. How do I solve this?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need for regex:

```
$url = 'http://localhost/whatever/index.php/something/cms-abc.html?___SID=U';
$parts = parse_url($url);
echo basename($parts['path']);
```

or even just

```
echo basename(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH));
```

Comment: I still hat to cut off the trailing .html, but that was easy. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean "behind cms-abc"?  Your regex should match this:

```
/cms-abc.html?__SID=U
```

Do you mean you don't want the stuff after the question mark?  Then replace the `.` with "any character except a question mark" which is `[^?]`.

Finally, if you're breaking apart URLs in PHP, look at the `parse_url()` function.  It exists, it's code you don't have to write, and it works without having to test it, unlike code you write.

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Answer (score 1):

"I want to get the **cms-abc** from that string." So, everything from/including "cms" up to (but not including) the dot:

```
/cms[^\.]*/
```